# Why does this semantic segmentation network have no softmax classification layer in Pytorch?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to use the following CNN architecture for semantic pixel classification. The code I am using is [here](https://github.com/meetshah1995/pytorch-semseg/blob/master/ptsemseg/models/segnet.py)

However, from my understanding this type of semantic segmentation network typically should have a softmax output layer for producing the classification result.

I could not find softmax used anywhere within the script. [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.00561.pdf) is the paper I am reading on this segmentation architecture. From Figure 2, I am seeing softmax being used. Hence I would like to find out why this is missing in the script. Any insight is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using quite a complex code to do the training/inference. But if you dig a little you'll see that the loss functions are implemented [here](https://github.com/meetshah1995/pytorch-semseg/blob/master/ptsemseg/loss/loss.py) and your model is actually trained using [`cross_entropy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy) loss. Looking at the doc:

> This criterion combines log_softmax and nll_loss in a single function.

For numerical stability it is better to "absorb" the softmax into the loss function and not to explicitly compute it by the model.
This is quite a common practice having the model outputs "raw" predictions (aka "logits") and then letting the loss (aka criterion) do the softmax internally. 
If you really need the probabilities you can add a softmax on top when deploying your model.